# does anyone know if the cosmossdb emulator supports graph api for local dev - or just documentDb api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cosmosdb

Does the emulator running locally only support documentDB formats?

(explorer only seems to show collections).

Not ready to jump straight into azure and wanted to have a go locally first with graph api and Java.

Answer (score 2):

The Cosmos DB emulator exposes the same API surface as the production service, and supports all protocols (DocumentDB, MongoDB API, Tables, Graph).

You'll be able to use all graph operations against the emulator. However, the built-in data explorer only lets you create DocumentDB/MongoDB collections (that's just a limitation of the data explorer, not of the core functionality).

Comment: great - just trying to setup environment in case and having a fight with idea gradle and dependcy resolution.  had to create a new project to get the classes to resolve in the ide - weird.  thanks for the info will give it a go shortly

Comment: @David .... do you know the connection strings for Table & Graph API when using Emulator? The Emulator documentation only talks about DocumentDB and Mongo API.

Comment: @Gaurav For connecting to the local Emulator use the below connection strings. 
endpoint: `https://localhost:8081/`
authKey: `C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==`
database: `your-db-name`

Update the port accordingly. The important thing to note is the unique universal AuthKey for all local emulators.

Comment: @Gvancha As u have mentioned that update the port accordingly for Graph API. But the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) does not contain any information regarding port settings for Graph API.

Comment: @Jagrati Yes the documentation does not call it out explicitly. The emulator uses 8081 as default port. So if your emulator started successfully use 8081. In case if your 8081 port is already in use, the emulator prompts you to explicitly mention the port using `/port=port` argument.